# Can't import GStreamer in python

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspbian

I'm trying to include GStreamer in a python file but I keep 
getting:

> ImportError: No module named gst

I tried to install gstreamer packages but it says its already installed.

I am running raspbian jessie on my aspberry Pi

Comment: Can you specify what code output this error?

Answer (score 0):

You might be having problem with caps, its Gst not gst. Try this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst
```